# How to stretch an image to full width with its height fixed

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to implement the carousel [like in this website](https://www.yamibuy.com/zh). I tried using the exact same image from the given website and did something like

```
div{
    height: 780px;
}

img{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
<div>
    <img src = 'xxx'></img>
</div>
```

Of course, this will not work as expected since it will change the aspect ratio of the image thus messing with its quality. I think what they did was somehow only make the image sized as something like 700px * 780px, then extend it horizontally using just the background color.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right.

On that site, they are setting the height of the image to `480px` and setting the width to `auto`

The `img` is contained in a `div`. That `div` has the `background-color` set dynamically by JavaScript. They are using color values associated with each slide's background color.

```css
.img-container {
  background: #f5a738;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2STW.png' />
</div>
```

Here's an example with a different background color so you can see where the image ends:

```css
.img-container {
  background: #a33;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-container img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class='img-container'>
  <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2STW.png' />
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for when the container is smaller than the image. I.e. It won't resize and keep its aspect-ratio

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just tested it on Chrome and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Copied your snippet to a JS fiddle but added a varying width animation for the image container: https://jsfiddle.net/qp6m8Log/ . OP asked for image to stretch and keep aspect ratio. In the fiddle what happens is the image isn't stretching but moving to stay centered and pops out of its container when container width is smaller than image. This  could work if you don't wish to actually stretch an image and you have the same color on all 4 edges of your image. Just not a very large use case.

Comment: I see. Thank you that is very clear! Just wondering do you happen to know what is the best way to find out the color of the background image using javascript? Is that even possible? Or probably they just hard coded that into their database?

Comment: @devsandbox I think this answer looks like what I want. At least it seems to be consistent with what the referred website is doing. If I use ```object-fit: cover```, it will crop parts of the image which is not quite exactly what the website is doing.

Comment: @Alex I'm glad this solution works for you. Just keep in mind the website in question you showed us isn't very responsive to different browser widths when you resize the browser. The image gets cut off. If you'd like to keep as much of the image on the page as possible then maybe a combination of these two methods. Here's an screenshot of the website resized: https://i.imgur.com/4hu2KCs.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object-fit: cover` to maintain the aspect ratio of images inside their containers.

The width of the box can change to anything while the image expands and contracts to cover it's parent element.

Added the animation for visuals only. Of course in your project you could set any width that makes sense.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body, img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
div {
  border-style: solid;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  animation-name: expand;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
@keyframes expand {
  100% {
    width: 30rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/0Zn5PLC.png'>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I am too new to upvote an answer. Thank you anyway for answering, and the animation is very nice!